# Foreign Key as Commposite Key-PK

Tags: java

```
public class ProductInfo 

    private String productInfoId;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

@JoinColumn(name = "ProductInfoId")

private List<Size> sizeList=new ArrayList<Size>();

}

public class Size{

private SizePK key;

}

@Embeddable

public class SizePK
{


    private String productInfoId;

    private String sizeDetails;

}
```

SIZE(ProductInfoId, productInfoId, sizeDetails)

05.03.2013 20:20:45.092 *WARN* [main] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter SQL Error: 1110, SQLState: 42000
05.03.2013 20:20:45.092 *ERROR* [main] org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter Column 'productInfoId' specified twice

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is how to get rid of the error you posted, being "Column 'productInfoId' specified twice" :

Change the name of `productInfoId` in the `SizePK` class to something else.

Comment: i wanted to add productInfoId as foreign as well as PK in  Size table, and specified structure works as well. If i change SizePK then, i can't achieve what i am expecting. With this i have only problem in insertion.